# What format does the 'Base Time' field in the 'Convert time zone' action expect?

Tags: date-time, power-automate

I am successfully converting:

```
12/25/2021 09:00:00 AM (Brisbane Time)
```

to `UTC` time, output in the `[u]` format, ie:

```
2021-12-24 23:00:00Z
```

using the `Convert time zone` action.

[image]

**Question**

You can see that the `Base time` value is in the format:

```
MM/DD/YYYY
```

Is it possible to instead use any of these:

```
DD/MM/YYYY  
DD-MM-YYYY  
YYYY-MM-DD
```

I cannot find the docs that explicitly state what format the `Base time` value should be in.

They all say enter a `timestamp` or `datetime` but don't say *how* that value should be formatted.

**Related Reading**

[Date and time functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#date-and-time-functions)

[formatDateTime()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatDateTime)

[convertTimeZone()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#convertTimeZone)

[Standard date and time format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

[Custom date and time format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

[Converting time zone in Microsoft Power Automate](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/converting-time-zone-in-microsoft-power-automate-8bce2441-1859-4d76-2f51-985d9c96534d)

[W3C Date and Time Formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

[DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getalldatetimepatterns)

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the screenshot below, the following timestamps format worked for me for `onvertTimeZone(variables('TimestampYYYYMMdd'), 'Eastern Standard Time', 'UTC')`

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss=> 2021-07-19 08:50:00 - Worked
MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss => 07/19/2021 08:51:00 - Worked
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.0000000Z => 2021-07-19T08:55:00.0000000Z - Worked
```

However, **DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss** throws the error shown below

*Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at line '1' and column '6070': 'In function 'convertTimeZone', the value provided for date time string '19/07/2021 09:51:00' was not valid. The datetime string must match **ISO 8601 format**.'*

[image]